# What workflow (application or suite) is best for digital cinematography?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, photoshop-scripting, information-graphics, video, photography

Doing composites creates a workflow. This workflow may consist of various components that proliferate or enhance the larger composite. Composites build all components of post-production. Digital cinematography generally compiles in real time; using macros, scripts, etc. The question; What graphic design workflow (application or suite) is best for digital cinematography?

Comment: Your question is off topic here. Try http://video.stackexchange.com

Answer (score -1):

The best workflow for presenting a story:

1. Create a story which is interesting and novel enough worth making a movie
2. Hire a creative professional capable enough to find and define a good way to present your story in the media you want
3. Hire more professionals to make it real

If it happens that you are the only professional that you can use, start with pen and paper. If you can make a solid cartoon of your story, maybe not so finely drawn, but at least the result is solid as a story, start to refine it with more complex tools. Adobe CC set has a good collection (drawing, painting, editing video, making animations) if you do not need 3D modelling nor kinetic character models. But other sites than GDSE surely can give much finer hints of using Adobe CC set andmore advanced tools in motion picture applications.

Do not waste your time with the software if the pen and paper version isn't interesting. In theory it's possible that your creation is abstract - colors, forms and movements which are nothing without rich enough presentation, so scatching something on paper with a pen may look useless. It' isn't. If you have such idea you should still be able to put its skeleton (=what makes it novel and interesting) on paper. It's not especially highly probable that any program could create it for you without your own idea.